# Meteor / Node.js high availability with compose.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I signed up for compose.io to use with my Meteor app. After created a DB, compose said: Some drivers like Node (and Meteor) are not able to handle failover between mongos nodes.

What is our options to leverage compose.io high availability, instead of just connect to a single Mongo instance? Is it HAProxy like this? https://gist.github.com/sawanoboly/1366694